# Why I cant get selected radio button from asp:RadioButtonList control?

Tags: asp.net

I generate radio buttons:

```
    foreach (string header in headers)
    {
        XMLHeaders.Visible = true;
        rdHeaders.Items.Add(header);
    }
```

Here is ASP code:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="XMLHeaders" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="group">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdHeaders" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection ="Vertical">
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
          <div class="row1" style="padding: 3px; text-align: left">
            <asp:Button Text="B" ID="btnDescColumn" runat="server" OnClick="SetDescPoint" CausesValidation="False"/>
        </div> 
</asp:Panel>
```

Here how it looks in the view:

[image]

When **B** button is selected post back occured and this function is fired:

```
    protected void SetDescPoint(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var columnDesc = rdHeaders.SelectedItem;
    }
```

At the event hendler above I try to get the selected radio button but, I get `null`.

How do I get selected radio button ?

Comment: Are you generating the radio button items in the page load event? you may just need to wrap your radiobutton for each in a If !Ispostback check.

Comment: I am new to asp can you show example please?

Comment: Remove asp:Panel and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your page load event where you generate your radio buttons, wrap it with a Page.IsPostBack check like so:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    foreach (string header in headers)
    {
        XMLHeaders.Visible = true;
        rdHeaders.Items.Add(header);
    }
}
```

This will ensure your radiobutton list is not regenerated on your page postback. What is most likely happening is the postback is rebuilding the radiobuttonlist which clears any previous selections if you have viewstate disabled.

Comment: but in the view I see the previous selection,the selection that was made before postback call

Comment: can you post more of you code behind so we can see a bigger picture of whats going on?